How to install flashing as a retrofit to protect rim joist below door threshold?
In a 1980 addition, the rim joist is exposed around a set of monolithic concrete slabs the addition was built on. More on the crazy slabs in this post, along with pictures of the exposed joists: How should this addition's concrete foundation be reinforced, if at all? I hired a contractor to install flashing on the rim joists that were unpainted. Penny wise and pound foolish when I was triaging a lot of deferred maintenance, I didn't have them flash all the rim joists. Now the paint is flaking off some painted sections, especially below the addition's door threshold. I have no experience with flashing but it doesn't seem that complicated. Most articles I read about it are focused on more standard setups and new construction.
How do I go about flashing these wood joists? For the white-painted joist that already has some flashing on top of the joist, I figure it is as simple as buying some white thin metal, tucking it under the existing flashing and tacking it into the wood, with the bottoms flared out slightly to send water away from the joists and out onto the concrete. Are there specific parts I should look for, for the sheets, edges, or bottom flaring? I am especially unsure about how to approach the edges under the door threshold, on top where it meets the door threshold. Do I just tuck the metal under the door threshold?
It seems like there's little room between the joist and door threshold, so that's where I'm unsure how to approach it. Is it enough to tack on a 'kick plate' to cover that joist from weather? People tend to kick that spot anyway, which is part of why the paint is removed, but I'm trying to discouraging that and have a mat to wipe boots instead.




For reference, here's how the unpainted joists looked before and after professional flashing installation.
How it looked when I arrived:

How a contractor installed flashing:


door threshold appears to be a trim piece. what id behind it?

Yes, pull off the "riser" beneath the door and see what the framing behind looks like.  Replace it with a PVC board if you don't care for the upkeep.

Pulling off the riser seems like I might be opening a can of worms, when I just wanted to protect the riser. How do I pull it off without causing more harm? And I'm okay with some upkeep but want to minimize construction materials toxicity. So I'd rather use metal than paint, and I'd rather use paint than PVC.
